# IPhone SDK: detect which touch came first on a 2 touch max application

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touchscreen

Coding inside the function
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
receiving 2 touches in the "event" variable, how can one detect which touch has lived longer?
i know i could use global variables and in the touchbegin just update these variables, but I rather do it the better way, if there is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I stored pointers to the touches. saving a timestamp manually, found no other way.

Answer (score 1):

How about comparing the UITouch timestamp properties?

Comment: That should do it.  timestamp tells you: "The time when the touch occurred"

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't do it, the timestamp of a touch is updated on each event, even in the touchesMoved. so you can't use it which touch started first.